# Java: time complexity of basic operations

Tags: java

I'm going to make some investigations about dividing large arrays/matrix computations among multiple threads. But I need to know the relative time complexity of Java basic operations.

**For instance:**

```
int a = 23498234;
int b = -34234;
int[] array = new int[10000];
int c = a + b; // 1
int c = array[234]; // 2
String 1 (summary of two integers) is 10+ times faster than string 2 (memory access)
```

or `(i & 1) == 0` is 10+ faster than `i % 2 == 0`.

**Question:** Can you supppose time relations between next operations:

- `+`, `*` and `/` operands (suppose on Integer type)
- memory access
- starting new thread

Comment: Java is not a [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). I would not anticipate the benchmarks you're collecting to be consistent between JRE releases.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how does Java8 optimize multithreading?

Comment: Do you think I can answer that in under 600 characters? Also, how does that have anything to do with your question above? My point is that optimizations are added into the JVM regularly, and since the JVM is inherently hosted you'll get different results based on many external factors; the load on the host, the version of the JVM, the platform of the host, the disk utilization, the number of cores, etc.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Only one way to find out: measure.

Comment: @assylias yes, I completely agree with you. I just trying to figure out what should I measure. Arrays of which size. On how many cores, etc. I want to narrow my estimations

Comment: Use a proper micro benchmark tool (for example jmh) and start writing tests. FYI most operations in your list will run in one or two cpu cycles, except the array allocation which needs to zero out 10000 ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance timing, there are many confounding factors.  Rather than try to get exact timings, it's better to understand what's going on and measure what you can.

The [time utility](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) will give you detailed stats on an executable, but keep in mind you're timing the JVM which is running the code, not just your code.

You might try the [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) disassembler too -- ultimately you'll want to know how your individual operations break down into java bytecode, and the amount of time it takes to execute certain key bits.

Example source code:

```
public class T {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
       int x=2;
       int y=3;
       int z=x+y;
       System.out.println(""+x);
   }
}
```

Compiled, then disassembled:

```
$ javap -c T
Compiled from "T.java"
public class T {
  public T();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iconst_3      
       3: istore_2      
       4: iload_1       
       5: iload_2       
       6: iadd          
       7: istore_3      
       8: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      14: dup           
      15: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      18: ldc           #5                  // String 
      20: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      23: iload_1       
      24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      27: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      30: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      33: return        
}
```

Look at code #6 - that's where the actual addition is happening.

One thing you need to establish is how the operations you're interested in turn into bytecode.

Within the JVM itself, you can use `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` as a way of timing, but it won't give you sub-ms resolution.  You can also use `System.nanoTime();` to get higher precision time, (in the sense that it's sub-ms resolution) but it's less accurate.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits The JIT will perfomr many optimisations on top of the bytecode.